# ND Filter for Agfa Super Isolette

Tags: film, medium-format, agfa

I'm interested about the Agfa Super Isolette. I know it accepts 29.5mm filters, but I'm not sure if I can fit a LEE System for long exposure.
Assuming I can find a 29.5 to X step up filter, I'm afraid the Lee Holder may hit the base of the door below the lens (see [here](https://www.kenrockwell.com/agfa/super-isolette.htm)).

Has anyone ever tried?

Comment: The minimum diameter of step-up rings I found is 37mm and we talk about 9 rings, so the system will be away from the door (if you find 29.5 to 37 ring(s).

Comment: Do you currently have a Lee system you're looking to use with this? Do you just need ND filters for long exposure, or do you intend on using ND grads as well?

Comment: I have a 100x100 lee system. I only do long exposure, but haven't figured out how to connect it to this 29.5mm

Answer (score 1):

I was going to make this a comment.

There’s probably a better alternative to the Isollette or the Lee Filters. I mean compactness is the big advantage of the Isollette but if you’re carrying a tripod and a filter case full of system, that’s kind of lost in the shuffle. On the other hand a screw on filter makes an Isollette compact again. And it won’t block the rangefinder windows.

The Lee filters holder is likely to obscure just about any non-SLR viewfinder (or a view camera). So there’s a good chance you will be mounting the whole thing after composing with a rangefinder or TLR.